# FULLTEXT query wont work when add 2 rows after MATCH

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, full-text-search

Following problem: If I add in the query after `MATCH` only `text` or only `title`, the query works fine and I get a array with the values. But when I added after MATCH the two rows `title` and `text` like that MATCH (title, text)  the query wont works and I get `Undefined variable: result`. I cant find the problem by myself and I think its the right syntax. 
My error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Both title and text have FULLTEXT index how I written above...

```
    $keywordsonetoeight = implode(',', $keywordse[0]); 
                try {
                        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=loginsystem",$user,$password);

                        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // 
                         $sql = "SELECT id, autorid, autor, title, text, time 
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH (title, text) AGAINST ('$keywordsonetoeight')
ORDER BY id DESC"; 
  if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
      // then after fetchColumn
     $result = $res->fetchAll();
   }
```

Comment: Add SQL error handling to your code and print the SQL error message to get yourself and us started in debugging. Also, you can try to execute the sql command in your favourite mysql manager application as well.

Comment: Yeah thank you, I forgot that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you do not have the appropriate fulltext index. Probably you indexed title and text columns individually, but now you are trying to do a fulltext search on both of them, which requires a combined fulltext index.

I would add `FULLTEXT (title,text)` index to your table and then you can do a `MATCH (title, text) AGAINST ('$keywordsonetoeight')`